# train_test_split not removing y train and test variables after index slicing

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding, train-test-split

I've used `train_test_split()` numerous times with index slicing, but for some reason it's retaining the predictor values for both y train and test sets. Below is example data, along with train/test slicing and shapes.

Original data example:

```
nypd_dummy.head(3

      borough   status
start 
2016  BRONX     ATTEMPTED
2017  BROOKLYN  ATTEMPTED
2018  BRONX     COMPLETED
```

Example data:

```
    nypd_dummies = pd.get_dummies(nypd_dummy)
    nypd_dummies.head(3)

          borough_BRONX borough_BROOKLYN status_ATTEMPTED status_COMPLETED
start     
2016      1             0                1                0
2017      0             1                1                0                
2018      1             0                0                1

X_dummies = nypd_dummies.iloc[:, 2:]
y_dummies = nypd_dummies.iloc[:, :2]
xtrain_dummy, xtest_dummy, ytrain_dummy, ytest_dummy = train_test_split(X_dummies, y_dummies, test_size=0.3)

print 'x train:', xtrain_dummy.shape, 'x test:', xtest_dummy.shape
print 'y train:', ytrain_dummy.shape, 'y test:', ytest_dummy.shape

x train: (3, 2) x test: (1, 2)
y train: (3, 2) y test: (1, 2)
```

Ultimatel I'm aiming to create a model that predicts the borough - is it not slicing correctly because I'm pulling predictor values from multiple columns as opposed to one single output?

Comment: Can you provide a little piece of `.txt` that one can load with pandas, then explain clearly what's the output you have, and what should have been the expected output ? To me, x/y train/test seems correct. But I might have misunderstood : hence the need for clarification on my part.

Comment: i added original code example; file derives from csv fomat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will produce Ys dataframes with the following structure (for both train and test):

```
       borough_BRONX  borough_BROOKLYN
start                                 
2018               1                 0
```

Since you wish to have a single estimation (predicting 'borough' class), you probably want to have a single label column. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) is a tutorial on dealing with categorical data in pandas.